# My CNN model is getting stuck at epoch 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The training gets stuck during the first epoch. I am training a CNN model with 22,000 training examples.

Jupyter notebook just keeps processing and doesn't run anything after the first epoch, running code on keras 2.2.4 with python 3.7.
This is my code for a CNN which is trained using images from the folders train and test. But whenever I try training it, the program seems to get stuck at epoch 1/10 all the time, i left it on overnight for 8 hours and it hasn't moved along at all, any fixes I could try?

```
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, 
Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, GlobalMaxPooling2D, 
GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import keras.backend as K
K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')

train_dir = r"D:\\Downloads\\cat vs dod\\PetImages\\train"
test_dir = r"D:\\Downloads\\cat vs dod\\PetImages\\test"


img_width, img_height = 300,281
input_shape = img_width, img_height, 3

train_samples = 22998
test_samples = 2002
epochs = 30
batch_size = 500


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255)



train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')

test_data = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides = (1, 1), input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides = (1, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer = 'rmsprop',
            metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.build(input_shape)
model.summary() 


model.fit_generator(
        train_data,
        steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
        epochs = epochs,
        validation_data = test_data,
        verbose = 1,
        validation_steps = test_samples//batch_size)

model.save_weights("D:\\Downloads\\cat vs dod\\simple_CNN.h5")
```

Comment: Can you post the training screenshot? One advice is to try to reduce the training examples.

Comment: Have you tried running this on a cloud with GPU?

Comment: What is the size of images? Do they vary?

Comment: No, the size of images remain the same. i have tried reducing the number of training examples, still the epoch gets stuck at 1.